# Background color darker stepwise

Tags: html, css

I have a menu, wrapped in a `<ul>` and I want the background of the `<li>`s to become darker the lower in the list the `li` is located. It's a fixed amount of `li`s.

I was thinking of giving it a `background: rgba(0,0,0,x);`, where the x would go from 0.1 to 0.6 in 5 steps (so .1 darker every step).

Of course I could target every `li` manually and change the background color accordingly, but I was wondering if there is any way to do this with purely CSS. I know it's possible to do with jQuery, but I want to know if there is a function in CSS that can do this, without me being aware of it.

Comment: With css you could do ul li:nth-child(1) etc.

Comment: No. there is no 'function' in CSS that will increment values as you suggest.

Comment: Might be possible only with some hacks. Would all the `li` have only one line worth of content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the number of `li` is known you can use % based color-stops on a linear gradient as mentioned by @Megajin

```css
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:50%;
    border:1px solid grey;
    background: linear-gradient(
        to bottom,
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1) 0%, 
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.1) 20%, 
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2) 20%, 
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2) 40%, 
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3) 40%, 
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3) 60%, 
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4) 60%, 
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4) 80%, 
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 80%,
        rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) 100%);
}
li {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I have to tweak your answer so it works with my exact situation, but it seems like this is exactly what I need! Thank you! P.S Please check the percentage build-up, there are some mistakes in there :)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend JS to do styling but if you're lazy you could probably do something:

```
var menuDarkness = 1;
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ul li").each(function(){
   $(this).css({background: "rgba(0,0,0,0."+ (menuDarkness++) +")"});
});
});
```

However using nth child would probably be the cleanest solution:

```
ul li:nth-child(1) { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);)
ul li:nth-child(2) { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);)
...
```

Note that adding these in a different order will have different effects, since nth-child selects every 1st or 2cnd row. so defining the first last will result in all of them having the same colour.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be using CSS3 gradients.
You don't have to do much just define the background and see the magic do all the work for you:

```
#yourUl{
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(yourColor, yourDarkerColor); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background: -o-linear-gradient(yourColor, yourDarkerColor); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(yourColor, yourDarkerColor); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background: linear-gradient(yourColor, yourDarkerColor); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

Comment: This would not give each `li` a separate **single** color..which seems to be the request. If you add color-stops based on the number of **known** `li` it would work.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes you are right. Still a gradient can be used on the whole menu or on single `li`.

Comment: Exactly what @Paulie_D says. Of course a gradient can be used on the whole menu or on a single `li`, but then I'd have to target each `li` manually anyway and then I can just use a solid background.